# How to use NServiceBus Performance Counter from inside IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, nservicebus

Is there a way to write to NServiceBus performance counter from process hosted by IIS, **not** NServiceBus Generic Host?
Or, generally speaking, is there a way to use NServiceBus performance counter **other** than running the GenericHost with profile specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the performance counters when self hosting by calling

Configure.With()
...

.EnablePerformanceCounters()

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/unicast/NServiceBus.Unicast.Monitoring/Config/MonitoringConfig.cs#L36

This assumes that you're using the 3.0 version of NServiceBus

Comment: that's nice, still I'm forced to stay with 2.6 version. Talking about 2.6, is the PerformanceCounters profiles the **only** way NSB provides to access this performance counter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) class to open an existing performance counter and update the value of the counter. You can also create new instances if the counter is instanced. You will have to use the various constructors depending on how you intend to use the performance counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the Transport layer on your own to plug in some counters.  Check out [this post](http://adamfyles.blogspot.com/2010/10/getting-started-with-nservicebus-part-7.html) on custom counters.